# Creating sparse matrix from dense matrix without initializing the dense matrix firstly

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

For a NLP task, I am creating creating a document term matrix of which the dimensions are 4280 x 90141 with >98% zero's. The dense representation of this matrix requires a lot of memory and thus I would like to create it as a sparse matrix.

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16505670/generating-a-dense-matrix-from-a-sparse-matrix-in-numpy-python) they suggest to use Scipy. But as far as I understand, it requires the initialization of the dense matrix, before it makes the sparse conversion. Is there a package/available code that creates a sparse document-term representation without initializing a dense matrix firstly?

I am thinking about something like:

```
dense_doc_term = []

for doc in corpus:
    dense_doc_term.append(Counter(doc))
```

Would that be a good approach?

Comment: `This requires a lot of memory and thus I would like to create a **dense** representation for this matrix.` This doesn't sound right. Do you mean sparse?

Comment: Sorry for the unclarity. No, I mean that I want create a representation that only include non-zero values

Comment: Yes, that's the sparse matrix, which only indexes the non-zero terms, not dense.

Comment: Thanks, is it better now?

Comment: Spend some reading the sparse matrix docs.

Comment: It sounds like you want to just use this: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html

Comment: There are plenty of more recent [scipy] [sparse-matrix] tagged posts.

Comment: @CJR, doesnt that require me to use the fit_transform() method whenever I want to perform calculations (such as getting the total count of one word in all documents?)

Comment: Basically a sparse matrix is created from arrays of row coordinates, column coordinates, and corresponding values.  There are variations for special layouts, but for a start focus on the `coo` format and its inputs.  The docs also describe the storage.  It helps to experiement, making small matrices and examining the attributes.